# Don't understand value in elasticsearch explain result

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, scoring

I am learning about the results of asking for explanation in elasticsearch. I understand the biggest part of it, there is however one value that I cannot find information about. below is the explanation part of a simple match query with one term in one field I have done. This is the result:

```
_explanation:
  value: 4.715253
  description: "weight(name:love in 604) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:"
  details:
  - value: 4.715253
    description: "fieldWeight in 604, product of:"
    details:
    - value: 1.0
      description: "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:"
      details:
      - value: 1.0
        description: "termFreq=1.0"
    - value: 4.715253
      description: "idf(docFreq=57, maxDocs=2382)"
    - value: 1.0
      description: "fieldNorm(doc=604)"
```

I am looking for the meaning of the number 604, does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

604 is the document id.

It's the id number you would pass in to [IndexSearcher.doc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#doc(int)) in order to fetch the documents stored fields from the index, usually after first searching on some other criteria (document ids are not guaranteed to remain constant).

Comment: In the javadoc of org.apache.lucene.search.Weight I found this description for doc: the document's id relative to the given context's reader. But does this relate to the _id of elasticsearch? I guess not because they are completely different.

Comment: Right, they are not the same thing.  Lucene's docid is used to fetch a document from the index, using a list of search results.  They are not meant to act as persistent keys.  As far as ElasticSearch is concerned, you don't need to worry about them.  The ElasticSearch _id is part of the unique, durable identifier that it assigns to documents (or allows you to assign).